# Left join on list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, join

I'm trying to do a left join on 2 list of dictionaries l1 & l2 based on the condition `l1.name = l2.name`. If the condition results in a match, the additional keys from l2 dict are added to l1 dict, else l1 dict remains as is.

Input

```
l1 =[{'id': 'id1', 'name': 'value1'}, {'id': 'id2', 'name': 'value2'}, {'id': 'id3', 'name': 'value3'}]
l2 =[{'key': 'key1', 'name': 'value1'},{'key': 'key2', 'name': 'value9'}]
```

Expected Output

```
result = [{'id': 'id1', 'name': 'value1', 'key': 'key1'}, {'id': 'id2', 'name': 'value2'}, {'id': 'id3', 'name': 'value3'}]
```

Code so far results in matched entries only. I need to add the unmatched dicts from l1 as is.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for dct in l1:
    d[dct["name"]].append(dct)

result = [{**d1, **d2} for d2 in l2 for d1 in d[d2.pop("l2name")]]
```

Comment: Loop through everything in `l2` and add to `l1` if they are not there. That is trivial.

Comment: I dont think you read/understood the question correctly. I dont need to merge lists. I need to join on elements within the dicts of each list... Please see the expected output for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Generator Expression to get the dict having the same value, and them update the first one

```
l1 =[{'id': 'id1', 'name': 'value1'}, {'id': 'id2', 'name': 'value2'}, {'id': 'id3', 'name': 'value3'}]
l2 =[{'key': 'key1', 'name': 'value1'},{'key': 'key2', 'name': 'value9'}]

for l1_item in l1:
   l2_item = next((item for item in l2 if l1_item['name'] == item['name']), None)
   if(l2_item):
       l1_item.update(l2_item)

print(l1) #[{'id': 'id1', 'name': 'value1', 'key': 'key1'}, {'id': 'id2', 'name': 'value2'}, {'id': 'id3', 'name': 'value3'}]
```